# Sending http requests without content-length or other headers

Tags: python, http, http-headers, httprequest

I am wondering if there exists a tool to send HTTP requests with given headers only.

I need this to test some application and want to observe the behavior of the application when some HTTP headers are missing.

Researched urllib2, httplib and pycurl but they add their own headers internally (in the best case, we can specify the value of these headers or make those values empty).

What I need is an utility where I have complete/transparent control of the HTTP headers I want to send in a request (so that I can send requests with missing `content-length`/`content-type` and so on) and the application just forms a request with these headers ONLY, without adding anything else internally.

I am able to do this with browser plugins.

Comment: Many of the libraries have a way of filtering the headers after they've been built, but before they're sent (although it can be pretty complicated in some cases). Is that good enough?

Comment: why don't you make a direct socket connection? manually crafting a HTTP request isn't that hard. or use `netcat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As abartnert points out, you can just use a socket for this if you'd like, but I think it's worth noting that CURL does what you require as well. From the man page at http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html :

```
Remove an internal header by giving a replacement without
content on the right side of the colon, as in: -H "Host:".
```

Comment: Presumably he's using one of the Python wrappers around libcurl, not popening the command-line tool. (If not, he should be…) But the point is still valid. Although, if he wants to specify exactly the headers he wants, he needs to have a list of all headers curl might ever possibly add, or he won't be able to tell it which ones to remove.

Comment: Thanks, writing a direct socket connection was my last resort, but will check CURL with the option suggested above.

Comment: @abarnert agreed, but it is a nice tool to use if you want to see what happens if an otherwise "normal" request is missing some particular header.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this, but it you're trying to completely control the requests at byte level, it may be easier to just use a socket:

```
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host, 80))
s.sendall(myrequest)
```

You can actually hook the socket up to some HTTP parser libraries after sending, but this may be a complicated. If you're after analyzing the entire result, you're probably better off just reading the whole result right from the socket:

```
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
result = ''
while True:
    buf = s.read(4096)
    if not buf: break
    result += buf
```